# jquery dialog lose foucs when scroll down browser

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, dialog

I have jquery(1.9.1) dialog implemented which has close button(not jquery dialog button, its my own image button) on it, when user click of the button dialog closes.

Issue:

button click event is not calling first time, When dialog is open and resize browser window and scroll browser down. i think dialog lose focus on scroll down.

can you let me know how to handle this issue. and this happens only in IE, not in firefox

html

```
<div id='dialogcontent'>
<input type='button' id='closedialog' value='close')
</div>
```

jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$("#dialogcontent").dialog({
height: 200,
width: "20%",
modal: true,
resizable: false,
draggable: false,
title: "Test",
});

$("#closedialog").on('click', function (e) { 
$("#dialogcontent").dialog('close');
});    

});
```

Regards,
M.Seenuvasan

Comment: Some code and maybe even a jsFiddle would be awesome to see :)